# Jquery code do not see special characters

Tags: jquery

I have a code that filters rows which i get from database query.. It works fine but it does not show the rows which start with a special character like "Ç, Ş, Ö, Ü"..

Forexample if i write Dar to input area it will list Daria, Darian, Dariko, Dartonal but if i write Çar to input area it will show nothing.. How can i fix this in this code? Thank you..

```
<script>
    var $rows = $('#table tr');
    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
            reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
            text;

        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
            return !reg.test(text);
        }).hide();
    });
</scrpit>
```